# Как реализовать multi-touch для кнопок?

Tags: android, multi-touch

Эх, надеялся, что больше проблем не возникнет. Напрасно, на финальном этапе вспомнилось про кнопки, и возникла такая проблема. Как я писал ранее, пользователь должен мочь нажимать их нон-стоп. Но если использовать onClick или onTouch, то если я зажму кнопку, то другие просто не будут реагировать на свои слушатели. Вопрос, как исправить и реализовать возможность "мультитача", т.е при зажатии одной кнопки (или использовании) другие должны реагировать на своих слушатели.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поддержка одновременных касаний устроена так, что нельзя просто слушать onTouch кнопками: надо вручную обрабатывать MotionEvent для активного View, и для этого все рисовать самому внутри активного View... Подробнее здесь: [Making Sense of Multitouch](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html).

Хотя, возможно, в последнем Андроиде что-то изменилось.

Comment: Немного непонял.

Comment: Там пример рисования в координатах, полученных при касании... На маркете видел пример, там при зажатии одной кнопки другие реагируют на нажатии, но если зажать 2, то уже нет.

Comment: Стандартные элементы (в частности, кнопки) не содержат нужной функциональности (как минимум до 2.0 это было так). Просто реализовать onTouchListener недостаточно. Правда, можно onInterceptTouchEvent попробовать. А так нужно рисовать кнопки самостоятельно и обрабатывать MotionEvent для вмещающего вида.

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747?tag=mantle_skin;content) серия из 6 туториалов про мультитач из книги "Hello, Android".

Comment: Видел. Не нахожу того, что мне нужно. (У меня эта книга даже скачана где-то.)